# process hacker: how to start a new task? (As task manager does)

Tags: windows-7, process, task-manager

When I *terminate* a task, for instance explorer.exe, how can I start it again using process hacker? (In task manager, we need to click on "create a new task")

(On windows 7)

Comment: could you please take the time to explain your down vote?

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for your reply. You assume that I did not spend time, but you are mistaken. I did't find anything answering my question in process hacker forum / and google. The most basic things are often the most difficult to find, because nobody talk about it. I did not fully understood what the windows "run" thing is (and I probably still don't). Don't forget there is many things you ignore, things that other people would find very obvious.

Comment: You can also just right click the task and restart it instead of terminating it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its as simple as:

1) Click `Hacker`

2) Click `Run`

3) Type in `explorer`

4) Click `Ok`

[image]